# Filter PropertyInfo by attribute enum value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enums

I have some custom properties against each of my Models as below

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class FieldAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private FieldFor _fieldFor;

    public FieldAttribute(FieldFor fieldFor)
    {
        _fieldFor = fieldFor;
    }
}
```

The type FieldFor is an enumeration.  So i can declare this against a field like so

```
[Field(FieldFor.Name)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Now to get a list of the properties on my model that have this custom attribute, i use the following

```
List<PropertyInfo> props = new MyModel().GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(FieldAttribute))).ToList<PropertyInfo>();
```

Now i have the list of all properties that have my custom attribute, how can i get which property has a FieldFor value of Name??

I am doing both queries separately as i have to get the values for many properties on my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the attribute using [GetCustomAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx) method, then you can access it's members:

```
foreach(var prop in props)
{
    var fieldAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttribute<FieldAttribute>();
    var value = fieldAttribute.FieldFor;
}
```

It would be useful to add a public property to get FieldFor's value.Right now you have only a private field.

```
public FieldFor FieldFor { get { return _fieldFor; } }
```

Using linq:

```
props.Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<FieldAttribute>().FieldFor == FieldFor.Name);
```

Comment: instead of a foreach, can i do this in a linq query?

Comment: I have just realised i didnt have a public property myself, duh! Thank you, perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
var props = new MyModel()
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(prop =>
        {
            var fieldAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttribute<FieldAttribute>();
            if (fieldAttribute != null)
            {
                return fieldAttribute.FieldFor == FieldFor.Name;
            }

            return false;
        })
    .ToList();
```